# Changing an SSIS dts variables

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

In an SSIS package I have a For..Each container that enumerates all (*.*) the files in a folder.

In that For..Each container I have a component-level variable 'fileComments' of DataType 'String'.

In that For..Each container I have a script task. With a ReadWrite entry for 'filecomments' (amongst others)

In that script task, I have some code :-

```
Dim Comments As String = Dts.Variables("User::fileComments").ToString
```

which allows me to read the value of that variable, but if I try to allocate a value back to that variable, I get  a **Property 'Item' is 'ReadOnly'** blue squiggly underline.

How do I change the vlaue of that variable (or get the value out of the script task so I can use it later in the flow) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is a common trap check this article out:

http://www.programmersedge.com/?p=1350

you basically need to use the Dts.VariableDispenser object to lock or declare the variable as read / write in the script task.